# Textarea doesn't send long text, short text is ok

Tags: php, forms, apache, post, textarea

I have form:

```
<form method='post' action='script.php'>

    <textarea id='main' name='text'></textarea>

    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='1'> 
    <input type='hidden' name='a' value='ulozitclanek'> 
    <input type='submit' name='button' value='Save'>

</form>
```

If I type short text into a textarea and submit, then in script.php I already have my text in variable `$_POST['text']`. However if the text is about 70000 character long, it isn't in `$_POST['text']`. I can see net log from Firebug and my text is in encoded string, which was sent by my browser to the server. But in `$_POST` array is my text missing.

This problem I have only on production server, when I test this script on localhost, it works also with long texts.

Is there any server option, which limits maxlen of post values?

In PHPinfo, I can see `post_max_size` set to 20M, there must be another problem, but I can't solve it on my own :-(

Any ideas?

Tanks.

Comment: Do you have enough RAM?  Check your server logs.  There's always PHP notice messages in there, in this case it might be helpful

Comment: Possibly a special character somewhere in the text, or an un-escaped quote breaking things.

Comment: I tried post 70000 charecters 'a' and problem is still here.
I don't know server HW. But script is normally running (it saves empty text into database with ID I send...) - I dont think so, that it can be caused by RAM... I can send an email to hosting support, but i dont expect solving my problem.

Comment: How are you testing this? What tells you that it's working?

Comment: It's working, when i find my text in $_POST['text'] variable. This problem is only on production server, on my localhost it is ok, so it must be in config of server? 
You can try it on your own here: http://administrace.bmhd.cz/test.php
If you post short text, it works (text will appear in $_POST array), in case of long text, it doesn't.

Comment: Problem solved. It was limit for POST variables on server. Thnx for your time and be careful about webhosting config. I've lost several hours by solving this problem :-(

Comment: If you ever encounter any missing POST values, try using var_dump($file = file_get_contents('php://input')); to see what is coming in raw. If it is missing in POST and the raw data, it is most probably a server or browser (client) problem. Plus if POST limits are reached in PHP (post_max_size), $_POST will be empty, not just missing some data: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Eda's Comment

> Problem solved. It was limit for POST variables on server. Thnx for
>   your time and be careful about webhosting config. I've lost several
>   hours by solving this problem